# Obj-C/iOS is a data structure like a plist okay or is something like coredata more easily used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I'm looking to build a reporting system, it will have canned reports, and user created reports, for each report I'll need the name, description, and the information that it will contain below is a structure I've jsonlint'ed to represent all the data a single report called "Review Progress" (inside the canned report structure) will need.

```
{
"Canned": [
    {
        "Name": "Review Progress",
        "Description": "Quick Look at ...",
        "Contents": {
            "Collections": [],
            "Filters": [],
            "Facets": {
                "Review Status": [
                    {
                        "Reviewed": {
                            "value": "300",
                            "enabled": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Not Reviewed": {
                            "value": "150",
                            "enabled": "false"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Am I barking up the wrong tree here by creating a series of dictionaries and arrays as accessing items inside of it for setting up the tableview will start to look something like this?

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.reports[indexPath.section][@"Reports"][indexPath.row][@"Name"];
```

Would anyone suggest a different approach like coredata/some sort of DB instead for ease? I ask as users will be able to create their own reports which will have to have the same data.

Comment: I say .plist is fine, even `NSUserDefaults` would work. With the .plist, you could put in Documents folder and enable iCloud sync.

Comment: It depends on what you intend to do with the data. A larger data set and/or complex operations (sorting, filtering, adding deleting, editing, etc.) would probably fit core data better. This answer has some good guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883957/620197

Answer (score 2):

A quick way should be to use [JSON Accelerator](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12) (free)
to generate object models form your JSON.

And then add to your "top" generated class model the category provided by this repository:

https://github.com/psineur/NSObject-AutomagicCoding

to easily load/save the dictionary representation (i.e. plist/json structured data) to the document folder

This will be quite the same than

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.reports[indexPath.section][@"Reports"][indexPath.row][@"Name"];
```

But more cleaner in my opinion thanks to object models