# Should I Use Core Data or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, core-data, webservice-client

I'm developing an application for the iPhone which gets all data from a database from a web service. I receive the information in JSON format and make constant calls to the web service for data. My question is should I be using core data? Right now I just make a request to the web service use the information I need and make calls to data when needed. But should I put the data into core data because I cannot figure if it would help or even make sense to do. Since there are thousands of rows of data on the server I can't imagine constantly saving information into core data in effect copying the database from the server onto the phone. That does not seem to make sense or be a good idea performance wise. Wouldn't I eventually run out of room in the core data database or use up too much room on the device? Maybe I'm not fully grasping the concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion there is no use of Core data as per your requirement. As you are asking your web service, every time you need new data. Your App is a web App, not a native one. Better work on how to speed up communication by using efficient data objects (you are already using JSON, thats good.). No need of CoreData according to me. Here are the links supporting my point:

[Why Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883879/why-should-i-use-core-data-for-my-iphone-app)
[Core data features overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. The application I'm developing is only a client side version to the website itself. Wouldn't even considered core data until someone mentioned it to me

Answer (score 2):

Of all of the ways to persist data on the iPhone, Core Data is the best one to use for non-trivial data storage. It can reduce the memory overhead of your app, increase responsiveness, and save you from writing a lot of boilerplate code.
According to [Tutorial of RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and [Tutorial of Objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html), you can get a good start.
And personally, using Apple's class is better for version control for your iOS Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no need to use core data at all since you're constantly fetching info from the web and you don't need the data to persist between app launches.

Answer (score 0):

@Marlow Charite storing data in local is based on requirement.

If you are having requirements like updated data must be loaded everytime for ex:NewsChannel. In this requirement latest data must be fetched everytime whenever user launches application,here there is no need of offline data storage.

If you are having requirements like updated data must be loaded as and when needed for ex:Social Network. In this requirement feeds loaded once then you can store in local db and load from local whenever user launches application.Implement pull to refresh for user to load more data.

Choosing sqlite db or core data storage for offline storage. [This link will help you.](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think use Core data is no problem, sqlite can help you save or cache request data, just a light sqlite, include sqite3 or FMDB(Third-party libraries), not affect performance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use the core data but there is some limitation using core data like the query you search for it.

Otherwise you can use the sqlite database there will be no any limitation using this and you can search for any record with sqlite..

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

As a few other posters have said, if you are constantly fetching the data from the web, then there is no need to put in persistent storage. Writing back and forth between RAM and flash is a big performance hit.

If you do need persistent storage, and are developing exclusively for the iOS platform, then Core Data is a good way to go as it is fairly high level and integrates well with iCloud and other Apple services. Otherwise, if you are considering Android and Windows as well, I suggest going with sqlite or FMDB as sqlite's wrapper. Here is another thread I found:

[Core Data VS Sqlite or FMDB....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723923/core-data-vs-sqlite-or-fmdb)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input and the links! Looks like everyone is leaning towards my initial notion of foregoing core data as I'm pulling information from the server as I need